# has_many nested to many models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 4 different models in rails and there is a has_many and belongs_to association between them. For example:

```
class Apple < AR::Base
  has_many :bananas
end

class Banana < AR::Base
  belongs_to :apple
  has_many :oranges
end

class Orange < AR::Base
  belongs_to :banana
  has_many :berries
end

class Berry < AR::Base
  belongs_to :orange
end
```

Now, if I write, like `@apple.berries`, I should get the list of berries belongs to that Apple. So how should I define this association? One of my friend told me to use inverse polymorphic association. I don't know whether its related to the above issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need here is `has_many` + `through` relationship. Right now, an `Apple` object does contain `Berry` objects, but `Apple` object doesn't contain them directly. So we need to tell it explicitly like:

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bananas
  has_many :berries, through: :bananas
end

class Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :apple
  has_many :oranges
  has_many :berries, through: :oranges
end
```

Now, you can `berries` directly on an `Apple` object as well as on a `Banana` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Is there any other way to write an association between Apple and Berry

Comment: There is: you can store `apple_id` in `berries` table, but I think it would be redundant.